# Why I am getting duplicate records in the table #preweighting_data_dma?

Tags: sql, duplicates

```
SELECT respid, cq4_1, dma
INTO #preweighting_data_dma
FROM #preweighting_data a
LEFT OUTER JOIN #us_zip b
ON trim(a.cq4_1) = trim(b.zip_code);
```

Comment: Do you want to know why you are getting duplicates, or do you want to know how to prevent getting duplicates?

Comment: Because there are duplicate records in the table preweighting_data a? Because There are multiple results in `a JOIN b`?

Comment: No there is no duplicate data in preweighting_data a. I am getting duplicate after the join condition.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting duplicates because more than one row matches your conditions.

To prevent duplicates use the DISTINCT keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT respid, cq4_1, dma
etc...
```

Comment: I want to know why I am getting duplicates? Please clarify it more. In the table #preweighting_data there is unique data.

Comment: @kuldeepdabral You're getting duplicates because there's duplicates in your data and you've done nothing in your query to eliminate them

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have duplicates in `preweighting_data` before then the only other chance is, that the column `us_zip.zip_code` contains some duplicates.

You can check with this query:

```
select trim(zip_code), count(*) 
from us_zip 
group by trim(zip_code) 
having count(*) > 1
```

If you detect duplicates this way, then the 'LEFT JOIN' "propagates" then into your new table.